# Counter vote php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi all this my Php code to add 1 vote to table  .... and evey member have once vote ...

my code

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
<div id="poll">
<form action="poll_vote.php" method="post" >
<? echo $rows['id']; ?>
<input type="radio" name="vote" value="1" ><? echo $rows['name']; ?>
<input value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"  type="radio" select="yas"name="id"/> 
<input value="0"  type="hidden"  name="list_n" /> 
</div>
}
```

---  poll_vote.php ---

```
 if ( isset($_REQUEST['vote']) && ($_REQUEST['id'])){
$a = $_REQUEST['vote'];
$id = $_REQUEST['id'] ; 
$res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id ='$id'"); }    
if (  isset($_REQUEST['vote']) && ($_REQUEST['id'])){
$list_n = $_REQUEST['list_n'];
$_REQUEST['vote'] = $a;
$id = $_REQUEST['id'] ; 
$sql  = "UPDATE tabel SET $list_n='$a' WHERE id='$id' ";
$res =mysql_query($sql) or die ("خطااا".mysql_error());  } 
if(isset($_REQUEST['vote']) && ($_REQUEST['id'])){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ok')</script>";
}
```

The error that appears is
 error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0='1' WHERE id='7'' at line 1

Comment: $list_n='$a' WHERE id='$id'    **yields**   '0='1' WHERE id='7'

Comment: Please escape any data you are using in an sql query, don't use it directly. It's really unsafe, your code is vulnerable for sql injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a variable as a column name.

Your variable `$list_n` is 0, and `$a` is 1, so in your query, `$list_n='$a'` becomes `0='1'`. The 0 is then interpreted as a column name, which is invalid.
Instead of `$list_n` in the query, use whatever you've named that column. (Perhaps you want just `list_n`, without the `$`?)

---

Some unrelated advice: Indent your code. Your code was rather hard to read because everything started at the beginning of a line, which makes for code you can easil get lost in.
Instead of something like

```
if ($foo == 'bar') {
if (baz()) {
do_stuff();
}
}
```

consider writing

```
if ($foo == 'bar') {
    if (baz()) {
        do_stuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: list_n, without the $       Good anwser